# How to set and read pins on the parallel port from C++?

Tags: c++, serial-port, device-driver

I am helping a friend to finish a final year project in which he has this circuit that we want to switch on and off using a C++ program.

[image: image of what i want]

I initially thought it would be easy, but I have failed to implement this program. 
The main problem is that

- Windows XP and above don't allow direct access to hardware so [some websites](http://www.beyondlogic.org/porttalk/porttalk.htm) are suggesting that I need to write a driver or find a driver.
- I have also looked at some projects online but they seem to work for Windows XP but fail to work for Windows 7.
- Also, most projects were written in VB or C# which I am not familiar with.

**Question:**

- Is there a suitable driver that works for Windows XP and Windows 7, and if yes how can I use it in my code? (code snippets would be appreciated)
- Is there a cross platform way of dealing communicating with parallel ports?

Comment: Your original title led me to believe that you were looking for help with *the circuit* which would have been better on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. I hope that this is better.

Comment: Next issue: You write "parallel port" in the text (and I copied that for the amended title), your images says "printer port" and you've tagged it [serial-port]. You should be clear about which you mean as the answer depends on which you choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at codeproject: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/17ChannelLogicAnalyzer.aspx), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PaPiC.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/control_e_appliances.aspx). You'll find treasures.

The 1st link works for Windows 7 - both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: from studying these projects i realised that its so easy. Thanks

Comment: #include "pt_ioctl.c"
#define printerAddress 0x378

OpenPortTalk();//start the driver.

 outp(printerAddress, 0x01);

ClosePortTalk();

Comment: please answer and dont link more. i found 23 file in your first link and dont know how to compile and dont know which finction is work with lpt.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to write a driver or anything -- you just call [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a filename like `"LPT1"` to open up a handle to the parallel port, and then you can use [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write data to it.  For example:

```
HANDLE parallelPort = CreateFile("LPT1", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if(parallelPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // handle error
}
...
// Write the string "foobar" (and its null terminator) to the parallel port.
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes.
const char *data = "foobar";
WriteFile(parallelPort, data, strlen(data)+1, NULL, NULL);
...
CloseHandle(parallelPort);
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to write data for an "intelligent" peripheral that understand some protocol, but just use the state of the various pins of the parallel port to switch on/off some loads (via optoisolators, ULN2803 & co.); in such case, your approach doesn't work.